# Multiple definition of std::map error

Tags: c++, dictionary

Also, I am compiling with g++-4.9 and -std= c++11

I have this exact map in my board.h file:

```
map <string,string> dirFull = {
    {"no", "north"},
    {"so", "south"},
    {"ea", "east"},
    {"we", "west"},
    {"nw", "north-west"},
    {"ne", "north-east"},
    {"sw", "south-west"},
    {"se", "south-east"},
};
```

And then I feely start using it in another function in my baord.cc file (i.e. `dirFull[no]`)which includes the .h file. I get this error:

```
Board/board.o: In function `__gnu_cxx::new_allocator<std::_Rb_tree_node<std::pair<char const, std::string> > >::deallocate(std::_Rb_tree_node<std::pair<char const, std::string> >*, unsigned long)':
/u6/yhavryshchuk/cs246/1161/a5/CC3K/Board/board.cc:11: multiple definition of `dirFull'
main.o:/u6/yhavryshchuk/cs246/1161/a5/CC3K/main.cc:20: first defined here
```

I have found multiple answers to this question, so I'm not sure what I should do. Some say I should use extern. some say a declaration should go in the .h file, but the definition should go in a .cc file.

Comment: have only one definition in a `.cpp` file, then in the other `.cpp` file use `extern map<string, string> dirFull;`, and it should work.

Comment: There is only 1 definition. It is only being used in 1 .cc file.

Comment: Two compilation units, two definitions. Accept the answer and use `extern`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`dirFull` is defined (not just declared) in both `board.cc` and `main.cc`.

You could use the keyword `extern` to declare, but not define for a second time, the same variable.

e.g. `extern map<string, string> dirFull;`

---

The following won't work if you have the same in another compilation unit:

```
extern map <string,string> dirFull = {
    {"no", "north"},
    {"so", "south"},
    {"ea", "east"},
    {"we", "west"},
    {"nw", "north-west"},
    {"ne", "north-east"},
    {"sw", "south-west"},
    {"se", "south-east"},
};
```

It will produce an `dirFull initialized and declared in extern` error as you mention in the comments.

---

### First option

If you have `base.h` for example:

```
#include <string>
#include <map>

std::map <std::string,std::string> dirFull ={
    {"no", "north"},
    {"so", "south"},
    {"ea", "east"},
    {"we", "west"},
    {"nw", "north-west"},
    {"ne", "north-east"},
    {"sw", "south-west"},
    {"se", "south-east"},
};
```

And then have `Main.cpp`:

```
#include "base.h"


extern std::map <std::string,std::string> dirFull;

int main()
{
    dirFull["no"];
}
```

Then it will work.

---

### Better option

Might be better to have `base.h`:

```
#include <string>
#include <map>

extern std::map <std::string,std::string> dirFull;
```

then have `Main.cpp`:

```
#include "base.h"

std::map <std::string,std::string> dirFull ={
    {"no", "north"},
    {"so", "south"},
    {"ea", "east"},
    {"we", "west"},
    {"nw", "north-west"},
    {"ne", "north-east"},
    {"sw", "south-west"},
    {"se", "south-east"},
};

int main()
{
    dirFull["no"];
}
```

With this last option it is nice to see the declarations in the header and the definitions in the .cpp (or .cc) files.

Comment: It is not in main. 100% not in main. And extern gives another error: `dirFull initialized and declared in extern`

Comment: Perhaps main has an `#include` that does?

Comment: @user5759490 Initialization has to be done in one of the `.cc` files.

Comment: Yes after I moved them to the .cc file, everything started working! Thanks